# C# Parameterized query - parameters not being replaced with set value

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, parameter-passing, npgsql

I'm passing a query and parameter from a WinForm to a database class. The

The code on the Form looks like this:

```
string selectedComp = "CPSI";
string catsQuery = "SELECT id, category, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, reference1, reference2 FROM masterfiles.xref WHERE company_name = '@company' ORDER BY category, old_value";

Db categoriesData = new Db();
dgvCategories.DataSource = categoriesData.GetData(catsQuery, selectedComp);
```

And in my database class my code to populate the datatable/set is this:

```
public DataTable GetData(string selectQuery, string selectedComp)
{
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@company", selectedComp));

    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", selectedComp);
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@company", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    //cmd.Parameters["@company"].Value = selectedComp;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);
        conn.Close();

        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

But putting a breakpoint at `NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);`, `selecctQuery` hasn't changed - the `'@company'` is still in the query.

What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the quotes: `WHERE company_name = @company`

Comment: @DStanley and madreflection, that makes sense, but I still am getting `@company` in the query. I also tried the three commented versions of replacing the parameter, but still `@company` isn't getting replaced after removing the single quotes from the query string.

Comment: You need to remove the quotes in the catsquery not the parameter

Comment: @Tintow, Yep - did that. Looks like this now: `string catsQuery = "SELECT id, category, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, reference1, reference2 FROM masterfiles.xref WHERE company_name = @company ORDER BY category, old_value";`

Comment: Where are you seeing the query with the parameter still intact? If you do a trace on the server the parameter will still show `@company` but will be "replaced" internally.

Comment: Try `cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("company", selectedComp));` looking at the [sample usage](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html) the `@` is not included in the actual parameter name

Comment: I have a breakpoint at the NpgsqlDataAdapter line and at that point it still has the `@company` in the query regardless of what I've done so far. If I add a catch to the try and look at the text of `Exception ex` it says "column 'company' does not exist." Is this a Npgsql or PostgreSQL-specific issue maybe?

Comment: @DStanley - removing the `@` didn't do the trick, either I also tried `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("company", selectedComp);`, as your referenced page has it written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root problem is that you're passing the *query* to the data adapter instead of the *command*. Change

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn);
```

to

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

I would also use `using` to dispose of all objects, and don't close the connection until the dataset is filled:

```
using(NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
using(NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
{

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("company", selectedComp));

    conn.Open();
    using(NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    conn.Close();

    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Hi @D Stanley, do you know why I can still fill the DataSet when I never use conn.Open()? Is the Connection managed by the DataAdapter?

Comment: @BenjaminLichtenstein Yes - if you don't open the connection then the `DataAdapter` will open (and close) it for you. You still need to dispose of it, though.